# Issues with JS Discord Bot[Music]

Tags: javascript

i'm creating a *Discord Bot* with *JS*, and when I turn it on, the console returns me:

> (21:21:19) - [ERROR] - TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object

Can someone help me?
Code:

```
async function playMusic(conn, entry = 0) {
  const song = queue[entry];

  try {
    const stream = ytdl(song, { 
      quality: 'highestaudio',
      highWaterMark: 1<<25
     });

    stream.on('info', info => {
      curSong = info.title;
      logger.info(` | Tocando: ${curSong}`);
      updatePresence(`► Tocando: ${curSong}`);

      if (listeners <= 1) {
        dispatcher.pause();
        updatePresence(`❙ ❙ ${curSong}`);
        logger.info(` | Ninguém está conectado ao ${channel.music}, a musica foi parada.`);
      }
    });

    dispatcher = await conn.play(stream);

    dispatcher.on('end', () => {
      if (entry == queueLength - 1) playMusic(conn);
      else playMusic(conn, entry + 1);
    });

    dispatcher.on('error', err => {
      logger.error(err);
      if (entry == queueLength - 1) playMusic(conn);
      else playMusic(conn, entry + 1);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(err);
    if (entry == queueLength - 1) playMusic(conn);
    else playMusic(conn, entry + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the rest of your `try... catch...`?

Comment: What's `conn` in your code?

Comment: oh yes, i already corrected @khuynh